# private variable not updated in JsonRequest RequestQueue

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with a class in my Android app. I read a JSON, on debug I see the results of the request, mPlatList is filled in with retrieved data, but when the loop is finished, my object.mPlatList is empty.

EDIT : Going forward, it seems in getAllPlatsStrings function, java goes to the for loop before the getPlatList() call finished.
I've added logs, and a log.i(...) just before "return platListToString" is thrown before a Log.i.. in getPlatList method.

Looking on this deeper...

Here's my class:

```
public class PlatBank{
    private List<Plat> mPlatList = new ArrayList<>();
    private JsonReader mJsonReader;
    private String mRetour = "";


    public PlatBank() {
       
        String url = "xxx"; //works
        // Instantiate the cache
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(new File("cache") ,1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap
        // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

        RequestQueue requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache,network);
        requestQueue.start();

        JsonArrayRequest mJsonQuery = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                mRetour = response.toString();
                Plat mTempPlat;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        mTempPlat = new Plat("id", (String) response.get(i)); // is filled in ok
                        mPlatList.add(mTempPlat); // mTemPlat added to mPlatList ok
                        
                        //on debug with breakpoint, I can see mPlatList grows with every object from Json request
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mRetour = "KO";
            }
        });


        requestQueue.add(mJsonQuery);
    }
    
    
    public List<Plat> getPlatList(){
        return  mPlatList;
    }
    
    
     public String[] getAllPlatsStrings() {

        PlatBank lPB = new PlatBank(); //so if I'm not wrong, here I should have a PlatBank object, with all Plat in mPlatList attribute ?
        String[] mPlatListtoString = {};

        for (Plat plat:lPB.getPlatList()) { //getPlatList is always empty. Don't find why...
            mPlatListtoString[mPlatListtoString.length+1] = plat.toString(); //source empty so never enters in this loop
        }
        return (mPlatListtoString);
    }
}
```

Class runs without error, but my private list return is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just transformed constructor PlatBank to classic method PlatBankFill() and called new PlatBank().PlatBankFill() and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

Check `response.length()`. If it is more than 0 then it will work, otherwise `response` might have some problems. Also check the server side class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, response is good. 
In the loop response.lenth() I can see mTempPlat is well instanciated, with good data, and mPlatList.add works too.

If I put a breakpoint on mPlatList.add, I can see the list growing with all the elements. 

But after leaving the loop, mPlatList is empty...

Answer (score 0):

I’m surprised you’re not getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with this line

```
mPlatListtoString[mPlatListtoString.length+1] = plat.toString();
```

The size of an array is immutable, so once you define it as `{}` it is essentially size 0 and can’t accept any elements. Perhaps this would be better accomplished using the stream api such as

```
String[] mPlatListtoString = lPB.getPlatList().stream().map(plat -> plat.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray();
```

This eliminates the need for the loop altogether.

Comment: thanks for the answer. For the moment, I'm not able to enter this for loop lol so no error. 

I will take your suggestion ;)

Comment: Ah yes, that does explain why there’s no error!